# How to join column from table2 to table1 after a specified column of table1?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
Select table1.*, table2.column1  from table1 join table2 on table1.column1=table2.column1
```

It works, but it puts the column in the end of the `datagridview`, but i have to put `table2.column1`, after a specified column of `table2`, and i have to use `table1.*` and i cant use listing of the `table1`'s columns is it possible?

Comment: Why can't you list all columns explitely? `SELECT *` is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: _"have to put table2.column1, after a specified column of table2"_ So why cant you: `SELECT table1.*,table2.OtherColumn,table2.column1 ...`?

Answer (score 1):

And why exactly can't you use a list of all the fields?

**NO** , it's not possible to place a column in the middle of columns specified with `*` , not with pure SQL and not with dynamic.

Just specify them, don't be lazy, it's better practice:

```
SELECT table1.col1,
       table1.col2,
       table2.col1,
       table1.col3
 ..........
```

Comment: I think it's just a typo but actually OP hasn't said that he needs to  _"place a column in the middle of columns specified with *"_. He said: _"have to put table2.column1, after a specified column of table2"_. That's not a problem at all.

Comment: Maybe, but I think the typo is the explanation :) @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

> because i am using union queries, and the table names are changing and one table contains more colums than the other

if table1 differs, that above all should be a strong argument for specifing all needed fields separatly. In case of a new field in table1, your query would be broken, cause the number of fields will differ from the ones used in the next union.